# popup targeted for iphone

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari

This is pretty self explanatory.  How can I target only iphone for a popup.

Comment: With HTML? Can you explain more?

Answer (score 1):

For Javascript and/or PHP:

http://davidwalsh.name/detect-iphone

Answer (score 0):

[How do I detect Mobile Safari server side using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186734/how-do-i-detect-mobile-safari-server-side-using-php)

Will work with all web technologies -- not just php.