# Loading JS script for only iOS devices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I have a jQuery script I'm using on a site to allow fixed position background images on iPhone/iPad/iPod. However it seems to be clashing with another script I am using on the site that enlarges background images full screen. Luckily they're independent of each other, I don't need the clashing background image script to work on iOS devices and vice versa.

Is there a way I can specifically target IOS devices to serve a JS file? I initially thought about using some kind of IF statement and doing it on window size but that started to get a bit complicated and affects other non-IOS devices. It just needs to run something like this...

..."if IOS device then load scroll.js"

I know device/browser sniffing is frowned upon but I can't think of another way around this problem.

Comment: Use the user-agent matching in @Keltex's link.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the Mobile Safari user agent string to detect mobile safari server-side, see: [How do I detect Mobile Safari server side using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186734/how-do-i-detect-mobile-safari-server-side-using-php)

---

You can also do this in JavaScript:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad)/i))
```

See [iPhone & iPod Detection Using JavaScript](http://davidwalsh.name/detect-iphone) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Detect Mobile Browser](http://detectmobilebrowser.com/) (it has a library for javascript).

Comment: Seems like a lot of code to just detect specifically IOS, is there any reason why that would be a more suitable solution over the answer Justin Ethier gave? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

you can also try this

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/like Mac OS X/i)) {
                alert('Hi, you\'re browsing from an iOS device.');
}
```