# Whats the correct way of detecting someone is browsing my page with an iPhone?

Tags: php, iphone, browser, detect

I am trying to get the best way to detect iphone users and forward them to the micro version of the site...

I am using PHP

Thanks in advance

Lee

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+detect+iphone

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I detect Mobile Safari server side using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186734/how-do-i-detect-mobile-safari-server-side-using-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to look at http://chrisschuld.com/projects/browser-php-detecting-a-users-browser-from-php/