# How to distinguish the device is of android or iOS to send the push notification?

Tags: java, android, ios

I have to send Push Notification through java server, how can I detect the device is android or iOS?

Comment: while registering users or login service should also receive device_type .

Comment: What kind of push? GCM? SNS? APN? More info please.

Comment: For android GCM and for iOS APNS but in server side how i detect i have only device token.

Comment: See if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6770594/2055998) is of any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect mobile (iOS and Android) using JSP/Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770572/how-to-detect-mobile-ios-and-android-using-jsp-java)

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic to know device type by token. You have to send device_type while registering for push notification or login service . USE "ios" or "android" strings hardcoded for iphone and android against against device_type. Thats how you know which token is against which device.
Send ios notifications via APNs or GCM to ios or android devices respectively

Answer (score 0):

> I have to send Push Notification through java server, how can I detect
>   the device is android or iOS?

Well the implementation of push notifications in every platform is completely different! in both you don´t need to know the platform.

Comment: he is asking about distinguishing android or iOS device .